# Microsoft Teams Chatbot not responding when using QnAmaker, Bot hosted by Azure Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

**Some Context:**
I am using QnAmaker to setup my Knowledge Base with my questions and answers. 
As so, I am hosting this bot on the Azure Bot Framework service, as a question and answer type bot. 
I have setup the following Channels; Microsoft Teams, Skype, Skype for Business and Web Chat. 
Currently the only channel that is working, I get a response from the chatbot, is through the webchat.

**My Problem:**
I would like to create an integration on the Microsoft Teams channel, but I am getting no response from the bot. This is through using the 1-on-1 chat test integration when Azure connects to MS Teams automatically. As this didn't work I then set up an external webhook, documented here [Setting up an External Webhook](https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Fconcepts%2Foutgoingwebhook&data=02%7C01%7Cv-caju%40microsoft.com%7C7f1830a4d8fa4700830208d566de3e5d%7Cee3303d7fb734b0c8589bcd847f1c277%7C1%7C0%7C636528027088826111&sdata=nmZwNV7poteBYzpiReBuPdnZp1kyjN7pWnuQJZuaYSI%3D&reserved=0). After messaging my bot through the channel using the @botname syntax I get the following error: 
[image: Microsoft Chatbot Channel Error]

At the moment this is just a proof of concept for something greater so I am hoping to get some help to nail down an architecture of publishing our chatbots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your error: "Microsoft Chatbot Channel Error", doesn't show any error?
Please provide errors for channels that didn't work

Comment: Sorry attached the wrong picture

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Helen, I have since updated the link with the error

Comment: Can you please provide with the bot id so that we could investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I found through searching MS Teams Chatbot setup documents that I did not embed my authentication key given from MS Teams to Azure Bot Framework code/header.

I used the following links to troubleshoot my issue:

- [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview)
- [Outgoing Webhook](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook)
- [Test the Bot 1-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test)